# Need to put AdMob ad id in java code? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

For example, on one of my app screens where you have a Banner ad, you have the following code in the xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewPrincipal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adId" />
```

And also in java code has the following code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, String.valueOf(R.string.adId));
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

It seems that everything is working with this test id, but when I take the ID parameter in this java code, leaving:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this);
```

or

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "");
```

The ad keeps running without any errors in the app, so do I just need to set the ad id in XML? Is that in all the tutorials I've seen people putting the ID also in java code. If I leave the parameter with nothing, nothing goes wrong, it's like this parameter is useless, and when I get the ID from the XML code, that crashes app. Can I put the ad id only in XML code then?

Comment: Just a correction, I meant: MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.adId));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the second argument of initialize wrong. **It is supposed to be app-id of admob on ad-unit id.** The ad id is used normally only in xml views, where app_id is used in code to initialize ads for the first time. Read More [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
```

Comment: Oh yes, I understood everything! I was guessing that this ID you put in MobileAds.initialize had to be the ad id, the same one you put in XML, but it's the app id. Then I should just put the line - MobileAds.initialize (this, "MY_ID_APP"); -  on the onCreat of every activity that has an ad, right? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @joaovictor yes and no, you don't need to put it in every activity, rather, you Launcher Activity. From doc(developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) This needs to be done only once, ideally at app launch. Also to show appreciation, Accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try everything programmatically:-

```
LinearLayout adContainer = <container>;
AdView adView = new AdView(activity)
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(<your-publisher-id>); // you can use id from constants

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Place the ad view.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
adContainer.addView(adView, params);
```